# Correct way of applying OOP concept of Aggregation

Tags: java, oop, aggregation, composition

I'm fixing the OOP design of my system because I think the architecture is flawed. I've to rewrite the classes for correct Object Orientation application such as its inheritance, interfaces and aggregation / composition for proper code re-use and relationship.

Say I have Curriculum Class, Subject Class, School Year Class, Year Level Class and I want to apply the concept of `HAS-A` (**Aggregation**) as

Curriculum `HAS-A` Subject
Curriculum `HAS-A` Year Level
Curriculum `HAS-A` School Year
Subject `HAS-A` School Year
Subject `HAS-A` Year Level

Is it enough to do it like:

```
public class Curriculum {

   SchoolYear schoolYear = new SchoolYear();
   YearLevel yearLevel = new YearLevel();
}
```

or initialize it using the constructor:

```
public class Curriculum {

   SchoolYear schoolYear;
   YearLevel yearLevel;

   public Curriculum(SchoolYear sy, YearLevel yl ){
       this.schoolYear = sy;
       this.yearLevel = yl;
   }
```

or just create an instance of the class within a method like:

```
   public DefaultListModel getAllYearLevel(){
       YearLevel yl = new YearLevel();
       return yl.getAllYearLevels();
   }
```

which I don't think is correct because I don't see the point in recreating the same method just to say Curriculum class `HAS-A` YearLevel.

How can I implement or apply the `HAS-A` concept considering Curriculum is composed of year level, subject and school year?

At this point I can't proceed with setters and getters because I don't know which way is correct. I want to be able to properly apply OOP concepts.

I'd appreciate any advice or help.

Comment: #3 is not aggregation. The new thing you construct has no more relation to it's "parent" once you return it. Between 1 and 2 you could debate differences between composition/aggregation and association but that's pointless. Do what fits best for your case.

Comment: There's no arguments for these SchoolYear and YearLevel constructors? Which year? Which level? Are these value objects or they can be shared and have an identity of their own?

Answer (score 2):

The "right" concepts for **Association**, **Aggregation** and **Composition** are all about the lifecycles and relationships. So the most important questions are "Which objects can exist independently from which objects?" and "How strong is the relationship between two objects (A-owns-B, A-knows-B, A-composed-of-B)?"

If you want to use the **aggregation** concept for your classes `Curriculum` (as an Owner) it would mean `Curriculum` would have a `SchoolYear` and also would have a `YearLevel`, but they all have their own life cycles. So if you destroy `Curriculum` the other objects would still exist. This can be achieved like your second approach:

```
public class Curriculum {

   SchoolYear schoolYear;
   YearLevel yearLevel;

   public Curriculum(SchoolYear sy, YearLevel yl ){
       this.schoolYear = sy;
       this.yearLevel = yl;
   }
}
```

If you want a stronger relationship between them you need the **composition** concept, where A-is-composed-of B so their life cycles are the same. If you destroy A you also destroy B. This means B can not exist without belonging to A. Like a building is composed of Rooms, but can a Room exist without a building?
To map the life cycles you need to create `YearLevel` and `SchoolYear` when you instantiate your `Curriculum` like your first approach.

From my opinion you're fine with aggregation on this one. 
If you're adding `Subjects` to your `Curriculum` you should consider using composition.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach seems to be the best of them, first and third approaches seem to have much dependency between the classes which is not recommended.

Note that SchoolYeal and YearLevel should be interfaces or abstracts but not implementation otherwise we will be still stuck in the dependency issue.

Comment: Wny can't they be implemented? I wouldn't advise abstract classes because then you can't implement them as in the question

Comment: The idea is to ignore the implementation of the object todecrease the dependency between the two classes. in the first approach if we change the implementation of SchoolYear and we use for examle new implementation class "FutureSchoolYear" we will need to change that in class Cirriculum, in the other hand if we choose the second approach with SchoolYear being interface we only need to let the "FutureSchoolyear" implements this interface.
Abstract and interfaces are both ways to interface this object to the current class , its up to you to choose between them depending on the relation